# How to make olives to be used in salad?

Tags: salad

Hey i was trying something different, and want to serve olives as salad but don't know how to make that salty thing to be included in salad.

Comment: Olives are extremely common ingredients in salads. I don't know why you are having issues.

Comment: @Catija mightn't the OP be asking how to cure fresh olives?

Comment: @Dorothy the question is very confusing but, considering the comment on the answer, no, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Catija lost in translation :-) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, any salty/pickled ingredient becomes part of the overall salt (and acid) balance of a salad - since olives are salty but not INEDIBLY salty, you can decide to taste how much you want to include, and how fine you want to cut them - you could do everything between including them whole (maybe pitted) and cutting/grinding them to a mince, brunoise, or paste - or a combination of such. The trick is to reduce the salt (and maybe acid) you add to other parts of the salad.